# How to set contentInset for SwiftUI scrollable TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I am trying to recreate Telegram Messenger message TextField with SwiftUI. In the telegram app TextField has padding and when content scrolls, content appears in this padding area:

[image][image]

I am trying to recreate it with SwiftUI's iOS 16 `TextField<S>(S, text: Binding<String>, prompt: Text?, axis: Axis)` , where axis is `.vertical` with `.lineLimit(_ number: Int?)` modifier.

But when I apply padding and scroll, border inside content appears:

[image]

How can I achieve telegram's app UI with swiftUI `TextField`?

My source code:

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {     
    TextField(
        "MainInputView.Message.TextView", text: $messageInputViewModel.message,                    
        prompt: Text("MainInputView.Message.TextView", comment: "Message input placeholder"), axis: .vertical
    )                 
    .lineLimit(10)                 
    .padding(.vertical, 8)
    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    .background(Color.systemBackground)                
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: .init(width: 20, height: 20)))
}
```

Comment: It seems the vertical padding `padding(.vertical, 8)` is not added in the expected UI